# Spring WebMVC Exception Handling

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception, spring-web

I have a global exception handler that extends `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` that handles exceptions thrown from my `@RestController`. The JSON payload returned in the response includes an "exception" field. E.g.

```
{
     "timestamp": 01010101010101
     "exception": <some exception class>
}
```

After upgrading from `spring-webmvc` `4.3.22.RELEASE` to `5.0.8.RELEASE`, the `exception` field is missing. Any idea if this is a Spring change, or is this likely my code?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. `server.error.include-exception` is false by default. Setting it to true re-introduces this behavior.